# Finding corner start point on map with compass headings

Tags: coordinates, gps

I'm searching for an actual corner point of a piece of property on a map surveyed by the bureau of land management.  The corner has headings of N60° 09'E by S29° 26'E

How do I convert this point to latitude longitude so I can actually go out in the field with a GPS and find this corner?[image][image]

So the point im trying to find in the field is at the upper portion pointed out with the ball point pen. There is also 1 set of lat and long in the lower corner. I just need to know WHERE to begin. I can follow gps to next corner if i knew where to begin on the ground.

Comment: can you provide more info?

Comment: Those are Bearings only of 2 Property Lines. You have not posted enough information to find a corner. Please post the Survey or a link to it.

Comment: This claim is defined by "metes and bounds" as from https://www.blm.gov/sites/blm.gov/files/documents/files/Mapping%20a%20Claim.pdf   To work out the GPS position from the 35° 13' 45.1"N 106° 11 27.3W corner, you have to follow the lines west-ish 40.14+20.07 feet  along the S89° 56'W line, then  north-ish along the N0° 17W  for 39.93 feet plus the other numbers that get you to the  "ccc" point t othe SouthEast of your pen, and then follow the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That corner is near 35.2431872N 106.2058593W, coordinates which I found through using the the BLM section viewer near "San Pedro, NM, USA (Santa Fe County)" in Township 12N 7E Section 28, from the BLM map server at https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer and https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgis.blm.gov%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FCadastral%2FBLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI%2FMapServer&source=sd   You can see that these property lines are drawn on the map. It is likely that the corners, or at least the 'ccc' points have some sort of marker on them.  The closest 'ccc' point is near 35.2418233 -106.2049365.

[image: BLM Plat map]

(I misunderstood the question, thinking the plat was a mining claim measured in feet and hundredths, rather than a ~40 acre piece of property measured in 66-foot long chains.  The answer below is how you'd step work from a latitude and longitude by feet wit metes and bounds)

Go into the field with a GPS, along with a good compass and a 100' survey tape.

The corner and reference points are defined with "metes and bounds" (https://www.blm.gov/sites/blm.gov/files/documents/files/Mapping%20a%20Claim.pdf or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metes_and_bounds) to the 0.01th of a 66 foot "chain", far more accurate than an standard hand-held GPS, so you would need to measure from reference points, as the people who filed the claim used.

I can't see if there are any monument points on the corners of the map, so use the GPS to get to the 35°13'45.1"N 106°11'27.3"W corner and then use the "Metes and Bounds" survey lines to walk the 'ccc' reference points along the N 0° 17' W line that the piece of property is defined from.  If you can find a corner monument anywhere nearby, you should start from there.

From that 35°13'45.1"N 106°11'27.3"W  corner point, you have to follow the lines west-ish 40.14+20.07=60.21 feet along the S89° 56'W line (along 269.93° True), then north-ish along the N0° 17W (359.716° True) for 39.93 feet plus the other unreadable numbers that get you to the "ccc" point to the Southeast of your pen, and can follow on from there.

Comment: Thank you. Will try and digest and decipher all your information and head out there tomorrow.

Comment: I'd look carefully around the points labelled "ccc".  There might be some sort of marker on/in the ground.

Comment: Looking at the labels closer, the measurements are in "chains" of 66', where Sections" are a 640 acre square mile measuring 80 chains X 80 chains.  That makes more sense with "Section 28" being 80 units between Section 19 and "Section 27"

Comment: Oh so the very confusing numbers are chains. Thanks.. so i just need to multiply those lengths x 66. Gotcha. Thanks Dave X

Comment: Yes, but start at the 35.2431872N 106.2058593W corner location from my revised answer.